# How to make a specific ASP.NET page unavailable?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 web application. I want to prevent this application from serving a specific page. Is there any IIS setting I can specify to prevent requests to this page? Or any other way I can take this specific page offline or unaccessible without having to modify the code & redeploy?

If I delete the .aspx, will that throw a 404 or will it mean the end of the world?

*edit:* this application is running on IIS6

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using?  please specify in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your web.config

```
<location path="noaccess.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Users will get a not authorized error.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using IIS7.x you can install [the ISS URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) and then create a rule for this page.  You could do a 301 permanent redirect to another page (such as a static html file or aspx page) or a temporarily moved redirect.

If you are using IIS6 you can use the feature described in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/09/18/how-to-redirect-a-url-in-iis6-iis7-and-in-asp-net.aspx) which is also entirely valid for IIS7 and is discussed in the linked article.